# Delete every role

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to delete every role from a guild, but I can't figure out how to. This is what I tried:

```js
const guild = message.guild;
guild.roles.cache.forEach(role => role.delete());
```

When I run the command, I get an unhandled promise rejection error.

Comment: we can understand nothing from what you've given us. we need more detailed info

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Try doing `role.delete().catch(console.error)` to diagnose the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roles of a guild include `@everyone` (which is a role for permission purposes but can't be removed) and your bot may not have the correct permissions to delete the roles. A bot can only remove roles if it has the `MANAGE_ROLES` or `ADMINISTRATOR` role. Also, bots cannot remove managed roles (i.e. roles for a bot) or roles that are above its highest role.

This will delete every role that the bot is above:

```js
if (server.me.permissions.has('MANAGE_ROLES') {
  await Promise.all(
    server.roles.cache
      .filter(role =>
        role.name !== '@everyone' &&
        !role.managed &&
        server.me.roles.highest.comparePositionTo(role) > 0
      )
      .map(role => role.delete())
  )
} else {
  // do whatever you want if the bot doesn't have the permissions
}
```